# Docker Compose: Unable to run mysql, it will stop automatically

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

### mysql will stop automatically

All my settings are working.

Yesterday I encounter a problem that my mysql is not working anymore. If I up my  docker `docker-compose up -d` the mysql will run just a seconds and it will stop automatically.

See my logs

[image]

I already tried this solution 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint at some point, it's still not working.

Is there anyone who encounter this problem and can you please guide me how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your docker-compose.yml and the error it throws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically that is related to cache on your docker, try this command `docker-compose build --no-cache`. That worked for me.